# How do I retrieve a set number of records in date order using joins

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the right results from a query.

At the moment I have two tables, main_cats and products.

The result I am after is 6 records, in date order, with only one unique main_cat_id.

The basic table structures are

- Main_cats: main_cat_id, main_cat_title
- Products: product_id, main_cat_id, product_name, date_added.

I am hitting problems when I join the main_cat table to the products table. It seems to totally ignore the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT date_added, product_name,main_cat_title FROM ic_products p 
JOIN ic_main_cats icm on icm.main_cat_id=p.main_cat_id 
WHERE p.main_cat_id IN (1,2,12,22,6,8)
GROUP BY p.main_cat_id
ORDER BY date_added   ASC
LIMIT 6
```

If I leave the join out the query works but shows more than one main_cat_id and I cannot display the main_cat_title as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is (at heart) a "select min/max date per group and associated fields" question.

```
SELECT p.date_added, p.product_name, icm.main_cat_title
FROM ic_products p 
LEFT JOIN ic_products p2
 ON p.main_cat_id=p2.main_cat_id
 AND p.date_added > p2.date_added
LEFT JOIN ic_main_cats icm ON icm.main_cat_id=p.main_cat_id 
WHERE p2.date_added IS NULL
AND p.main_cat_id IN (1,2,12,22,6,8)
```

Let me explain: look at this table, being the first `LEFT JOIN` of the query above:

```
SELECT p.date_added, p.product_name
FROM ic_products p 
LEFT JOIN ic_products p2
 ON p.main_cat_id=p2.main_cat_id
 AND p.date_added > p2.date_added
WHERE p2.date_added IS NULL
```

This joins `products` to itself: it produces a table with every combination of `date_added` pairs within each category, where the date in the first column is always greater than the date in the second.

Since this is a left join, when the date in the first column is the smallest for that category, the date in the second will be `NULL`.

So this basically selects the minimum date for each category (I assume you want the minimum date ie earliest occurence, based off your `ORDER BY date_added ASC` in your question -- if you wanted the newest `date_added` you'd change the `>` to a `<` in the above join).

The second `LEFT JOIN` to `icm` is just the one in your original question, so that we can retrieve `main_cat_title`.

There is no need to `LIMIT 6` here because firstly, only one row is retrieved per `main_cat_id` thanks to the first `LEFT JOIN`, and secondly, your `AND p.main_cat_id IN (1,2,12,22,6,8)` only selects 6 categories. So 6 categories at one row per category retrieves 6 rows. (Or at most 6; if you have no items in a particular category of course no rows will be retrieved).

Comment: Only two months later...

Many thanks for answering this question mathematical.cofee.

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...

```
SELECT p.main_cat_id as cat_id, product_name,main_cat_title, MAX(date_added) FROM ic_products p 
JOIN ic_main_cats icm on icm.main_cat_id=p.main_cat_id 
WHERE p.main_cat_id IN (1,2,12,22,6,8)
GROUP BY p.main_cat_id
ORDER BY date_added   ASC
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I have tried the distinct keyword on the main_cat_id but I am getting 3 results with main_cat_id=1 and 3 with main_cat_id=2. Which is strange considering the DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: Try this : SELECT DISTINCT main_cat_id, product_name,main_cat_title FROM ic_products p 
JOIN ic_main_cats icm on icm.main_cat_id=p.main_cat_id 
WHERE p.main_cat_id IN (1,2,12,22,6,8)
ORDER BY date_added   ASC
LIMIT 6

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting 'ambigious' on main_cat_id, if I change to p.main_cat_id or icm.main_cat_id I get multiple main_cat_id's in the result. It seems to be something to do with the date_added or main_cat_title columns as when I remove these it works.